# How to specify a table storage name for Azure cloud diagnostic

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

I have created a could Storage account to be a destination of Azure cloud diagnostic. By default, there is `WADLogstable` which is created for me.

I like to change the table name per a role. For example, for the `Webrole` I would like to have `WebroleWADLogstable` and `WebServiceRole` write to `WebServiceRoleWADLogs` table.

In the Diagnostics Connection string I can only set storage account name.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: You can't do that. `WADLogsTable` table contains an attribute (column) called `RoleName` and you can filter the data for a particular role by querying on this attribute (along with `PartitionKey`).